# Space of Hilbert-Schimidt operators is complete?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the space formed by bounded operators on a separable Hilbert space such that $||A||_{HS}<\infty$, where

$$||A||=\sum _{n=1}^\infty ||Ae_n||^2$$

How to show the sub-space is complete (e.g. there is a convergent sub-sequence)?